# OpenCV : libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv

I recently installed Opencv-2.4.6
I wrote a code for bird's eye view transformation(it's not the final code).
With the earlier version of Opencv(2.4.3), it was being executed.

And now I am getting a error while running.

**error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory****
There are no compilation errors.

The code is:

```
// This code will take undistorted images as input and give the bird's eye view using them
// First we need to calculate the homography matrix
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define heightBirdEyeView 800
#define widthBirdEyeView 800    //earlier was 300 300
using namespace cv;         
using namespace std;

//global/
//camera parameters input

//resolution values
/*
float resolution_x=50, resolution_y=50;

//camera height and tilt
float height_camera = 1.25;
float tilt_camera=12;

//focal length in x and y
float focal_length_x = 354.05700;
float focal_length_y = 353.65297;*/

//intensity finding function
    // find the intensity for the transformed point

/*float findintensity(float corrected_x,float corrected_y)
{
int intensity;
if((corrected_x>=1&&corrected_x<=widthBirdEyeView)&&(corrected_y>=1&&corrected_y<=heightBirdEyeView))
intensity=(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))+(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))+(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))+(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)));
else
intensity=0;
return intensity;
}*/


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
//loading the undistorted image
Mat undistor_img=imread(argv[1], 1);
namedWindow("undistorted image");


int intensity_change=0;
Mat undistor_img_hsv;
cvtColor( undistor_img,undistor_img_hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);

imshow("undistorted image", undistor_img);
imshow("hsv image",undistor_img_hsv);
cout<<"size="<<undistor_img_hsv.rows<<" "<<undistor_img_hsv.cols<<endl; // for obs7.jpg the columns are 220 and the rows are 165
//cout<<"undistorted image="<<undistor_img_hsv<<endl;

// erode the image
Mat eroded;
erode(undistor_img_hsv,eroded,Mat());
imshow("eroded",eroded);

//dilate the image
Mat dilated;
dilate(eroded,dilated,Mat());
imshow("dilated",dilated);

Mat output;
resize(undistor_img_hsv,output,cv::Size(heightBirdEyeView,widthBirdEyeView));// this will be having the orthogonal transform
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<=heightBirdEyeView;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<widthBirdEyeView;j++)
output.at<uchar>(i,j)=0;
}
imshow("output",output);
//should have size as that of height and width of the bird eye view

//camera parameters input

//resolution values
float resolution_x=50, resolution_y=50;

//camera height and tilt
float height_camera = 1.25;
float tilt_camera=12;

//focal length in x and y
float focal_length_x = 354.05700;
float focal_length_y = 353.65297;

//generate transformation matrix
float H1[3][3]={resolution_x,0,widthBirdEyeView/2+1,
        0,-1*resolution_y,heightBirdEyeView,
        0,0,1};
Mat transformation_matrix(3,3,CV_32FC1,H1);
cout<<"transformation matrix="<<endl<<transformation_matrix<<endl<<endl;


//generate top view matrix
float H2[3][3]={height_camera/focal_length_x,0,0,
        0,0,height_camera,
        0,cos(tilt_camera)/focal_length_y,sin(tilt_camera)};
Mat topview_matrix(3,3,CV_32FC1,H2);
cout<<"topview matrix="<<endl<<topview_matrix<<endl<<endl;

//generate scale matrix
float H3[3][3]={1,0,undistor_img.rows,
        0,1,undistor_img.rows,
        0,0,1};
Mat scale_matrix(3,3,CV_32FC1,H3);
cout<<"scale matrix="<<endl<<scale_matrix<<endl<<endl;

//generate homography matrix
Mat homography_matrix=transformation_matrix*topview_matrix/scale_matrix;
cout<<"homography matrix="<<endl<<homography_matrix<<endl<<endl;

Mat transpose_homography_matrix =homography_matrix;
Mat temp_matrix =homography_matrix;

//cout<<"temp_matrix=" <<endl<<temp_matrix<<endl<<endl;

//transpose of homography matrix
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    transpose_homography_matrix.at<float>(i,j)=temp_matrix.at<float>(j,i);
}
//cout<<"transpose homography matrix="<<endl<<transpose_homography_matrix<<endl<<endl;

float bev_zero[heightBirdEyeView][widthBirdEyeView];        //bev_zero will be the new image matrix
for(int i=0;i<heightBirdEyeView;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<widthBirdEyeView;j++)
    bev_zero[i][j]=0;
}
Mat new_point_matrix; // this 3x1 matrix will be used to give new point for all old points in old image
//(undistor_img_hsv.rows,undistor_img_hsv.cols,CV_32FC1,bev_zero);
//cout<<endl<<new_point_matrix<<endl<<endl;
//new_point_matrix=
//Mat new_point_matrix;
float corrected_x,corrected_y;

Mat old_point_matrix;

//conversion from point to its new point
for(int k=0;k<undistor_img_hsv.cols;k++)
{
    for(int l=0;l<undistor_img_hsv.rows;l++)
    {
    float point[3][1]={k,
               l,
               1};
    Mat old_point_matrix(3,1,CV_32FC1,point);
    //get the new points for new view
    //corrected_x=bev_zero[0][0]/bev_zero[2][0];
    //corrected_y=bev_zero[1][0]/bev_zero[2][0];
    new_point_matrix=transpose_homography_matrix*old_point_matrix;
    cout<<"old point="<<old_point_matrix<<",new point="<<new_point_matrix<<endl; // every old point in the old image has got a new corresponding point

    //cout<<"new x="<<corrected_x<<", new y="<<corrected_y<<endl<<endl;
    //cout<<bev_zero[0][0]<<bev_zero[1][0]<<endl<<endl;
    //cout<<"new x="<<new_point_matrix.at<float>(0,0)/new_point_matrix.at<float>(2,0)<<endl;
    //cout<<", new y="<<new_point_matrix.at<float>(1,0)/new_point_matrix.at<float>(2,0)<<endl;x
    //new_point_matrix=new_point_matrix/new_point_matrix.at<float>(2,0);

    //find corrected values
    corrected_x=abs(new_point_matrix.at<float>(0,0)/new_point_matrix.at<float>(2,0));
    corrected_y=abs(new_point_matrix.at<float>(1,0)/new_point_matrix.at<float>(2,0));
    //cout<<"point= ("<<corrected_x<<","<<corrected_y<<")"<<endl;
    //cout<<"old point= ("<<k<<","<<l<<")"<<endl;
    cout<<"corrected_x="<<corrected_x<<endl<<"corrected_y="<<corrected_y<<endl;

    float intensity; // to store intensity values
    // based on the corrected values, find out the intensity points
    //cout<<findintensity(corrected_x,corrected_y)<<endl;
    if((corrected_x>=1&&corrected_x<=widthBirdEyeView)&&(corrected_y>=1&&corrected_y<=heightBirdEyeView))
{
intensity_change++;
intensity=(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))+(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))+(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))+(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)));
}
else
intensity=0;
cout<<"intensity="<<intensity<<endl;
//cout<<new_point_matrix<<endl;
cout<<floor(new_point_matrix.at<float>(0,0))<<endl;
cout<<int(new_point_matrix.at<float>(1,0))<<endl;
// now I just need to give this intensity value to the corresponding point for the old point
//output.at<uchar>(floor(new_point_matrix.at<float>(0,0)),floor(new_point_matrix.at<float>(1,0)))=intensity;
//cout<<"value="<<new_point_matrix.at<uchar>(0,150);
//cout<<"value21="<<undistor_img.at<uchar>(0,150);
//cout<<"pixel intensity at this point="<<new_point_matrix<<endl;

    cout<<endl;
    }
}
//cout<<"intensity changed "<<intensity_change<<" times."<<endl; 
//imshow("output",output);
//cout<<"old point matrix="<<old_point_matrix<<endl;
//cout<<"new point matrix="<<new_point_matrix<<endl;
//cout<<"pixel intensity at this point="<<new_point_matrix<<endl; //ERROR HERE
    //cout<<"changed new point="<<new_point_matrix<<endl;

/*

Mat p_new(3,1,CV_32FC1); // this will give the coordinates in the bird's eye view 
float corrected_x,corrected_y;
//float Floor_corrected_y,Floor_corrected_x,Ceil_corrected_x,Ceil_corrected_y,Ratio_corrected_x,Ratio_corrected_y;

int a=0,b=0;
// counters for if and else blocks

//now we need matrix with coordinates of the image plane, to be projected
for(int p=0; p<heightBirdEyeView;p++)
{
    uchar* data= undistor_img.ptr<uchar>(p);
    uchar* hdata= birdeyeview_img.ptr<uchar>(p);
    for(int q=0;q<widthBirdEyeView;q++)
    {
    //birdeyeview_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[0]=transpose_homography_matrix*undistor_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[0];
    //birdeyeview_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[1]=transpose_homography_matrix*undistor_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[1];
    //birdeyeview_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[2]=transpose_homography_matrix*undistor_img.at<cv::Vec3b>(q,p)[2];
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(q,p)=transpose_homography_matrix*undistor_img.at<uchar>(q,p);
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(q,p)=transpose_homography_matrix*int(undistor_img.at<int>(q,p));

    //cout<<transpose_homography_matrix*undistor_img.at<int>(q,p)<<endl;
    int M[]={q,p,1};
    Mat p_old(3,1,CV_32FC1,M); //holding the positions in undistorted image
    //cout<<transpose_homography_matrix*p_old<<endl;
    p_new=transpose_homography_matrix*p_old;
    //cout<<endl<<p_new;    
    //cout<<endl<<p_new.at<float>(0,0);
    //cout<<endl<<p_new[1];
    //cout<<endl<<p_new[2];
    //cout<<endl<<cvmGet(p_new,0,0);
    corrected_x=p_new.at<float>(0,0)/p_new.at<float>(2,0);
    corrected_y=p_new.at<float>(1,0)/p_new.at<float>(2,0);

    //cout<<"the pixel intensity to be assigned="<<(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
            //                          +(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))
            //                            +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
             //                          +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))<<endl;
    //cout<<"values to be greater than 1"<<corrected_x<<","<<corrected_y<<endl;
    //cout<<"those should be less than"<<undistor_img.rows<<"and"<<undistor_img.cols<<endl;
    //cout<<corrected_x<<" "<<corrected_y<<endl;

    if (((abs(corrected_y)>=1)&&(corrected_y<=undistor_img.rows))&&((abs(corrected_x)>=1)&&(corrected_x<=undistor_img.cols)))     
           {// Floor_corrected_y = floor(corrected_y);
             //Ceil_corrected_y = ceil(corrected_y);
             //Floor_corrected_x = floor(corrected_x);
             //Ceil_corrected_x = ceil(corrected_x);
            // Ratio_corrected_y = corrected_y-floor(corrected_y);
            // Ratio_corrected_x = corrected_x-floor(corrected_x);        
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q)=(1-(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
                  //                     +(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))
                  //                      +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
                    //                   +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*((int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)));
    //cout<<"if read"<<endl;
    //hdata[q]=(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*data[q] +(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*data[q] +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*data[q]+( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*data[q];   //works to some extent
    hdata[q]=(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x))            +(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x))+( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)) +( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x));    
    a++;}
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(q,p)=(1- (corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
          //                            +(1-( corrected_y-floor(corrected_y)))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(floor(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x)))
            //                            +(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(1-(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x)))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y),floor(corrected_x)))
              //                         +(corrected_y-floor(corrected_y))*(corrected_x-floor(corrected_x))*(undistor_img.at<uchar>(ceil(corrected_y), ceil(corrected_x))); 
//}

    else{
    b++;
    hdata[q]=data[q];
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q)=255;
    //hdata[q]=undistor_img.at<uchar>(round(corrected_y),round(corrected_x));
    //hdata[q]=(int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(q,p);//gives sm output
    //hdata[q]= undistor_img.ptr<uchar>(p,q);
    //hdata[q]= undistor_img.at<uchar>(p,q);//works to sm extent
    //cout<<endl<<"pixel value"<<(int) undistor_img.at<uchar>(p,q);
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(q,p)=undistor_img.at<uchar>(round(corrected_y),round(corrected_x));
    }
    //cout<<(int)birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q)<<endl;
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q)=0;}
    //cout<<"else read"<<endl;}
    //undistor_img.at<uchar>(p,q)=(int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(round(corrected_y),round(corrected_x));}
    //birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q)=124;
    //cout<<endl<<(int)undistor_img.at<uchar>(p,q);
    //cout<<endl<<(int)birdeyeview_img.at<uchar>(p,q);
    //cout<<"working here1"<<endl;
    }

}
//flip(birdeyeview_img,birdeyeview_img,1);
//  perspectiveTransform(undistor_img,birdeyeview_img ,homography_matrix);
//cout<<"bird"<<birdeyeview_img<<endl;
//cout<<"working here2"<<endl;
//cout<<birdeyeview_img<<endl;
cout<<"input channels="<<undistor_img.channels()<<endl;
//cout<<"grayscaled image channels="<<gray_undistor_img.channels()<<endl;
cout<<"output channels="<<birdeyeview_img.channels()<<endl;
cout<<"if was read"<<a <<"times"<<endl;
cout<<"else was read"<<b <<"times"<<endl;
imshow("bird's eye view image",birdeyeview_img);
cout<<"input size="<<undistor_img.rows<<"X"<<undistor_img.cols<<endl;
cout<<"result size="<<birdeyeview_img.rows<<"X"<<birdeyeview_img.cols<<endl;

//cout<<"working here3"<<endl;
*/
cvWaitKey();
}``
```

Can someone help what to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just open file called `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf`, then insert

```
 /usr/local/opencv/
```

then type: `sudo ldconfig`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you didn't install OpenCV properly, since the core library cannot be found. You have several options:

1. run `make install` (probably smth like `sudo` in Ubuntu will be needed) if you built the library yourself (look at the bottom of the http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)
2. As a quick-and-dirty hack - you can modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before running the executable, smth like:

   `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/myself/opencv/lib ./my_mighty_opencv_app`

(this is one long execution command)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using Anaconda and the path to the opencv library is:

```
/home/myhome/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib
```

and my solution is:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/etc...
```

It may work for other situations.  Just export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the folder where your OpenCV libs are located.

Answer (score 0):

I installed OpenCV on my Raspberrypi 3B following [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) tutorial and then got the same error you did. I found my solution [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-opencv/), by running `sudo ldconfig` after `sudo make install`.