# Matlab Libopencv error using Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, opencv, path

I am running into errors with `opencv`. I downloaded a package online and compiled each of the folders by `cd` into them and running `make` through the command line. But when I try using one of the functions, I run into this error: `libopencv_core.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The file its trying to reach is indeed there, since I checked this, but for some reason its saying its not. I am pretty bad at figuring out path problems but I think this is one of them. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: why is this a MATLAB issue?

Comment: you need to make sure the shared library is available on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that way your program can locate and load them at runtime.

Comment: @Lokesh I'm trying to use a matlab package which uses open_cv, and I thought it may have been something with compiling with matlab

Comment: @Amro, how/where can I find that path, the LD_LIBRARY? I'm really bad with path stuff, so its probably really obvious but Im not sure where it is.

Comment: @user1829924: you could see the output of `LD_LIBRARY` by using the command: `echo $LD_LIBRARY'. This particular answer maybe of use here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19174965/1815357