# Matlab - plot all the point level of a function

Tags: matlab

I have to plot this function:

**f(x,y)=4-x^2-4y^2**

and the result is this:

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-25:1:25);
z=4-x.^2-4*y.^2;
surfc(z);
```

[image]

The problem is that I would like to see all the ellipse in every level (of the range that I chosen) and not just one part of it... it is possible?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should use `surfc(x,y,z);`, otherwise the `x` and `y`-axis are shifted.

Comment: i tried to shift the axis but does not change anything

Comment: what do you mean with "see all the ellipse in every level "?

Comment: @GiovanniFar: Are you referring to isosurface? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19174965/1815357 or something on the lines of contour

Comment: @thewaywewalk i mean that i want to see the complete ellipse and not just one part... because in this way i cannot understand completely the plot

Comment: @GiovanniFar: Some of the full eclipses are outside of your data range `(-25:1:25)`. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: if you want to see more contours, you can use `contour(x,y,z,50)` and get a feel of your data range...

Comment: thanks with contour3(x,y,z,50) it's perfect